# How to decode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) provides a background of this `filename` parameter.

I need to write a script to access some files on a web server. The filename contains CJK characters which cannot be encoded in ASCII.

```
$ curl -I 'http://bj.baidupcs.com/file/f6f258963f3c5daaa154ed441db232e1?xcode=f5a142e99df965f6a3b4c502a3c55a73283ef282da2f5c14&fid=1107408242-250528-2625488475&time=1373046574&sign=FDTAXER-DCb740ccc5511e5e8fedcff06b081203-QSIMrWw%2FICWQuExpdtyijM0vbMM%3D&to=bb&fm=N,Q,U&expires=8h&rt=sh&r=210487178&logid=3893215518&sh=1'
......
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="【动漫之家汉化组】[最强会长黑神][第192话][黑神目泷依然健在][END].zip"
......
```

As you see, cURL decodes the filename properly. Firefox can also figure out the correct filename.

I wrote my script in Python. I tried [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) first:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r=requests.head('http://bj.baidupcs.com/file/f6f258963f3c5daaa154ed441db232e1?xcode=f5a142e99df965f6a3b4c502a3c55a73283ef282da2f5c14&fid=1107408242-250528-2625488475&time=1373046574&sign=FDTAXER-DCb740ccc5511e5e8fedcff06b081203-QSIMrWw%2FICWQuExpdtyijM0vbMM%3D&to=bb&fm=N,Q,U&expires=8h&rt=sh&r=210487178&logid=3893215518&sh=1')
>>> r.headers['content-disposition']
'attachment;filename="ã\x80\x90å\x8a¨æ¼«ä¹\x8bå®¶æ±\x89å\x8c\x96ç»\x84ã\x80\x91[æ\x9c\x80å¼ºä¼\x9aé\x95¿é»\x91ç¥\x9e][ç¬¬192è¯\x9d][é»\x91ç¥\x9eç\x9b®æ³·ä¾\x9dç\x84¶å\x81¥å\x9c¨][END].zip"'
```

The filename looks like a weird representation of Python bytes. The problem is that this whole thing is already a Python string. I can't think of a way to get the actual bytes to decode.

```
>>> type(r.headers['content-disposition'])
<class 'str'>
```

The underlying library `requests` uses is the `http.client` standard library. I tried it but got the same thing:

```
>>> import http.client
>>> conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("bj.baidupcs.com")
>>> conn.request('HEAD', '/file/f6f258963f3c5daaa154ed441db232e1?xcode=f5a142e99df965f6a3b4c502a3c55a73283ef282da2f5c14&fid=1107408242-250528-2625488475&time=1373046574&sign=FDTAXER-DCb740ccc5511e5e8fedcff06b081203-QSIMrWw%2FICWQuExpdtyijM0vbMM%3D&to=bb&fm=N,Q,U&expires=8h&rt=sh&r=210487178&logid=3893215518&sh=1')
>>> r=conn.getresponse()
>>> r.getheader('content-disposition')
'attachment;filename="ã\x80\x90å\x8a¨æ¼«ä¹\x8bå®¶æ±\x89å\x8c\x96ç»\x84ã\x80\x91[æ\x9c\x80å¼ºä¼\x9aé\x95¿é»\x91ç¥\x9e][ç¬¬192è¯\x9d][é»\x91ç¥\x9eç\x9b®æ³·ä¾\x9dç\x84¶å\x81¥å\x9c¨][END].zip"'
```

I'm using Python 3 on Windows.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a subprocess. The subprocess printed unicode text, but thought the OS's locale didn't allow anything outside of ASCII and printed something like what you have above. I fixed it by manually setting the locale: `os.environ['LANG'] = 'enUS.UTF-8'`. `LANG` might have been `LC_ALL`; I can't remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a UTF8-encoded (byte) string back as a Python 3 (Unicode) string. You'll have to do something like...

```
>>> s = 'attachment;filename="ã\x80\x90å\x8a¨æ¼«ä¹\x8bå®¶æ±\x89å\x8c\x96ç»\x84ã\x80\x91[æ\x9c\x80å¼ºä¼\x9aé\x95¿é»\x91ç¥\x9e][ç¬¬192è¯\x9d][é»\x91ç¥\x9eç\x9b®æ³·ä¾\x9dç\x84¶å\x81¥å\x9c¨][END].zip"'
>>> s = s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
>>> s
'attachment;filename="【动漫之家汉化组】[最强会长黑神][第192话][黑神目泷依然健在][END].zip"'
```