# Python requests module, how to handle filenames with special characters

Tags: python-requests

I have a problem with special characters when trying to post file as "multipart/form-data". When i try to post a file with special characters, the file is missing from the post. With no special characters my script works just fine.

How should I handle the filenames?

Works ok:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost/upload.ws', files={'file': open('test.txt')}, data=param, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Posts empty data as file:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost/upload.ws', files={'file': open('test_äöå.txt')}, data=param, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: Requests should never be seeing the filename in the first place.

Comment: Hrm. Maybe it is. Let me see something...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17495513/674064 is about received files, but maybe you need to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

try converting the string to unicode, like this:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost/upload.ws', files={'file': open(u'test_äöå.txt')}, data=param, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

or if the name is in a variable do it like:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost/upload.ws', files={'file': open(filename.decode('utf8'))}, data=param, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

its not a problem with requests library, python doesnt treat strings as unicode by default so it cant open the file ( it treats its name like ascii characters)

Answer (score 0):

Requests is probably extracting the filename incorrectly from the object. Try passing an explicit filename as a `unicode`:

```
..., files={'file': (u'test_äöå.txt', open('test_äöå.txt'))}, ...
```

Comment: Passing the name as unicode doesn't fix the problem. I tried to set the explicit filename with standard characters and then it works. {'file': ('test.txt', open('test_äöå.txt'))} works, but {'file': (u'test_äöå.txt', open('test_äöå.txt'))} doesn't.